# How to save embedded Google map to my account

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to save an embedded Google map with its pins to my account or my maps so I can view them in my Android mobile?

For example, here's a map with ATMs of my city: http://milmapas.com.ar/mapas-online/servicios-financieros/cajeros-banelco-caba

How can I "save" it so I can view it in mobile's Google Maps application (just like I can do it with my personal maps)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Embedded maps like these are not map objects like your personal maps. These are just normal google map, embedded in iframe with a javascript based overlay. Means all those points you see on the map, were added *after* the map was loaded on your browser. Google might not even be aware of it happening.